# get value of selected day from calendar in flutter

Tags: flutter, calendar

I am relatively new to flutter and my question is that I have a calendar widget, and whenever the user taps on any day, I want to display it to the user in a text field.
I have a rough idea that it should be done by setstate, but I am not sure how to implement it. Can anyone please tell me what am I missing? PS I know it's not very well-written piece of code.

```
    import 'package:employee_attendance/drawer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:employee_attendance/Button.dart';
import 'package:imei_plugin/imei_plugin.dart';



String calledinsideday(DateTime date, String usedfor) {
  // var show;

  if (usedfor == 'set') {
    var show = 'hello';
    show = date.toString();
    print(show + 'inside if');
    return show;
  } else {
    var show = 'in here';
    print(show + ' inside called');
    return show;
  }
}

class Attendance extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AttendanceState createState() => _AttendanceState();
}

class _AttendanceState extends State<Attendance> {
  CalendarController _controller;
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = CalendarController();
  }

  TableRow onerow(String heading, String value) {
    return TableRow(children: [
      TableCell(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                '$heading',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[900], fontSize: 18.0),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.005,
            ),
            Text(
              '$value',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.007,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Attendance'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
      ),
      drawer: MyProfile(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TableCalendar(
                initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
                calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
                    todayColor: Colors.blue[900],
                    selectedColor: Colors.blue[100],
                    todayStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 22.0,
                        color: Colors.white)),
                headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
                  formatButtonVisible: false,
                  centerHeaderTitle: true,
                  formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.brown,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                  ),
                  formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  formatButtonShowsNext: false,
                ),
                startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
                onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
                  // Date date = new Date();
                  // date.date = date.toString();
                  String please;
                  please = date.toString();
                  var x = calledinsideday(date, 'set');
                  print('XXXXXXX' + x);
                  print(date.toString());
                  // print("duhiud" + please);
                  // return please;
                },
                builders: CalendarBuilders(
                  selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                      // color: Colors.blue[100],
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        color: Colors.blue[100],
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        date.day.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                  todayDayBuilder: (context, date, events) => Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue[900],
                          //  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          shape: BoxShape.circle),
                      child: Text(
                        date.day.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      )),
                ),
                calendarController: _controller,
              ),
              Center(
                child: Table(
                    defaultColumnWidth:
                        FixedColumnWidth(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2),
                    border: TableBorder.all(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    children: [
                      onerow('Checkin status',
                          calledinsideday(DateTime.now(), 'get')),
                      onerow('Checkin time', 'Nothing to show'),
                      onerow('Checkin location', 'Nothing to show'),
                      onerow('Checkout time', 'Nothing to show'),
                    ]),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [link](https://flutter-examples.com/change-text-widget-text-dynamically/)
If anyone comes here for the same reason, this link gives a good idea

Answer (score -1):

This library will return you the day that you click and the list with others day if is selected, only use the `onDayAddedOrRemoved` function like this:

```
SmartCalendar(
                controller: controller,
                onDayAddedOrRemoved: (day, month, monthName, year, dates) {
                  print('Selected date: $year-$monthName-$day \n $dates');
                },
              )
```

Here is the link to the library
https://pub.dev/packages/smart_calendar

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, already edited the awnser to be more explicit